# Open executable file from graphics button without closing parent window

Tags: python, zelle-graphics

I've created a game "dice poker" using Zelle's graphing package, and have a button on the main screen which opens a text file.  The text file opens when the button is clicked, but the main window closes.  How can I keep the parent window open?

The button class is below:

```
from graphics import *
from tkinter import Button as tkButton

class Button():

    """A button is a labeled rectangle in a window.
    It is activated or deactivated with the activate()
    and deactivate() methods. The clicked(p) method
    returns true if the button is active and p is inside it."""

    def __init__(self, win, center, width, height, label):
        """ Creates a rectangular button, eg:
        qb = Button(myWin, centerPoint, width, height, 'Quit') """

        w,h = width/2.0, height/2.0
        x,y = center.getX(), center.getY()
        self.xmax, self.xmin = x+w, x-w
        self.ymax, self.ymin = y+h, y-h
        p1 = Point(self.xmin, self.ymin)
        p2 = Point(self.xmax, self.ymax)
        self.rect = Rectangle(p1,p2)
        self.rect.setFill('lightgray')
        self.rect.draw(win)
        self.label = Text(center, label)
        self.label.draw(win)
        self.deactivate()

    def clicked(self, p):
        "Returns true if button active and p is inside"
        return (self.active and
                self.xmin <= p.getX() <= self.xmax and
                self.ymin <= p.getY() <= self.ymax)

    def getLabel(self):
        "Returns the label string of this button."
        return self.label.getText()

    def activate(self):
        "Sets this button to 'active'."
        self.label.setFill('black')
        self.rect.setWidth(2)
        self.active = True

    def deactivate(self):
        "Sets this button to 'inactive'."
        self.label.setFill('darkgrey')
        self.rect.setWidth(1)
        self.active = False
```

How can I include a `command` argument that can open an executable in a fashion similar to this tkinter implementation:

```
import Tkinter as tk

def create_window():
    window = tk.Toplevel(root)

root = tk.Tk()
b = tk.Button(root, text="Create new window", command=create_window)
b.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Where the command can be `subprocess.run(['open', '-t', 'poker_help.txt'])` and still keep the original window open?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to make some assumptions since you didn't include top level code (e.g. you're on a Mac):

Zelle graphics, unlike tkinter and turtle, which is also built on tkinter, doesn't have an explicit `win.mainloop()` call to turn control over to the Tk event handler to idle awaiting events to happen.  Instead, you have to patch one together yourself, otherwise once you get the mouse click that fires off your button, the program falls through the end of the file and the main window closes:

```
import subprocess
from graphics import *
from button import Button

win = GraphWin()

help_button = Button(win, Point(150, 150), 50, 50, "Help")
help_button.activate()

quit_button = Button(win, Point(50, 50), 50, 50, "Quit")
quit_button.activate()

while True:
    point = win.getMouse()

    if help_button.clicked(point):
        subprocess.call(['open', '-t', 'poker_help.txt'])
    elif quit_button.clicked(point):
        win.close()
```

Where `from button import Button` brings in your button code above.  Another thing to check is your window is actually closing, and not simply being obscured by the new window opened atop it.